# CSS margin style to div boxes

Tags: css

Hi I've been spamming the dev tools in google chrome to try and add margins to my nav bar. The intended idea is to have margins that will allow me to create gaps between the boxes. Any help is appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/3jp1d0fe/8/

CSS

```
div.container {
    display: table;
    display: table-row;
}
div.column {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#c2ad80;
}
div.column a {
    color:white;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
div.column.current, div.column:hover {
    background-color: #a2884f;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column"><a href="/sites/SharePointSDLC/SitePages/Solution%20Assessment.aspx"> Solution Assessment</a></div>
    <div class="column"><a href="/sites/SharePointSDLC/SitePages/Design.aspx"> Design</a></div>
    <div class="column"><a href="/sites/SharePointSDLC/SitePages/Build.aspx"> Build</a></div>
    <div class="column"><a href="/sites/SharePointSDLC/SitePages/Deploy.aspx"> Deploy</a></div>
    <div class="column"><a href="/sites/SharePointSDLC/SitePages/Test.aspx"> Test</a></div>
    <div class="column"><a href="/sites/SharePointSDLC/SitePages/Live.aspx"> Live (BAU)</a></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    url = location.pathname.substr(1);
    $('a[href*="' + url + '"]').closest(".column").addClass("current");
});

$(".column a").click(function () {
    $(".current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).closest(".column").addClass("current");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this may help you..

```js
$(function () {
    url = location.pathname.substr(1);
    $('a[href*="' + url + '"]').closest(".column").addClass("current");
});

$(".column a").click(function () {
    $(".current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).closest(".column").addClass("current");
    return false;
});
```

```css
div.container {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}
div.column {
    display: table-cell;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#c2ad80;
    
}
div.row { display:table-row; }
div.column a {
    color:white;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    
}
div.column.current, div.column:hover {
    background-color: #a2884f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Solution Assessment</a>

          </div>
          <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Design</a>

          </div>
          <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Build</a>

          </div>
          <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Deploy</a>

          </div>
          <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Test</a>

          </div>
          <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Live (BAU)</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`margin`

> Applies to all elements **except elements with table display types other than table-caption**, table and inline-table. It also applies to ::first-letter.

[Source - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)

You could use `border-spacing` instead of `margin``

```
div.container {
    display: table;
    display: table-row;
    /* Added */
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:5px;
}

div.column {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#c2ad80;
    /* Added */
    border:2px solid white;
}
```

**SNIPPET**

```js
$(function () {
    url = location.pathname.substr(1);
    $('a[href*="' + url + '"]').closest(".column").addClass("current");
});

$(".column a").click(function () {
    $(".current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).closest(".column").addClass("current");
    return false;
});
```

```css
div.container {
    display: table;
    display: table-row;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:5px;
}
div.column {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#c2ad80;
    /* Added */
    border: 2px solid white;
}
div.column a {
    color:white;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    
}
div.column.current, div.column:hover {
    background-color: #a2884f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Solution Assessment</a>

        </div>
        <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Design</a>

        </div>
        <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Build</a>

        </div>
        <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Deploy</a>

        </div>
        <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Test</a>

        </div>
        <div class="column"><a href="https://www.google.co.uk"> Live (BAU)</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is an alternative that's great for other cases but I think I need to use margin because of the background. The aim is inbetween the worlds have a blank white space that seperates them rather than a square around each box

Comment: well, then try this. I've edited the `display` property of `div.column` to `inline-block`, so you could use `margin`. Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jp1d0fe/12/)

Comment: thank you for the help and advice, I've got it working now :)

Answer (score 1):

Here it is, I changed to use `background-color` by `a` instead of `.column` then added `padding` to the `.column` and then added hover effect to the `.column a` instead of `.column`

```
div.container {
    display: table;
    display: table-row;
}
div.column {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 2px;

}
div.column a {
    color:white;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color:#c2ad80;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
div.column.current a, div.column a:hover {
    background-color: #a2884f;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xmecnaqy/)